# ¿Cómo manejo las entradas por consola de un nombre?

Tags: c++

Tengo una práctica que consiste en hacer un programa que calcule el índice académico de una persona. El problema está en que cuando le pido el nombre al usuario, no sé si el usuario ingresará su primer nombre, nombre y apellido o el nombre completo. El error ocurre cuando se digita un espacio, el programa lo toma como otro dato y yo estoy acostumbrado a que el espacio sea tomado como un carácter. Lo he heredado de java.

¿Alguna idea de qué puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿Que has intentado?, puedes buscar: `c++ string input with spaces` y [edit] tu pregunta con el código que estés usando para mejorar las probabilidades de obtener respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::string cadena;
std::cin >> cadena;
```

El ejemplo anterior va a leer una cadena de caracteres **hasta** que se encuentre un espacio. De hecho esto es lo que dice la [documentación](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator-free/) de la función al respecto:

> Extracts characters from is and stores them in s as a c-string, stopping as soon as either a **whitespace** character is encountered or (width()-1) characters have been extracted (if width is not zero)

Para leer la línea al completo tienes que hacer uso de la función std::getline:

```
std::string cadena;
std::getline(std::cin,cadena);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad me ayudaron mucho!!

Comment: @Cokoro Si la respuesta soluciona tu problema no olvides marcarla como solución. De esta forma contribuyes a que el portal gane en usabilidad